# Questions about $\mathbb C[x]/(x^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given   $R$  is  the Ring $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x^2+1)}$
.Then  which of the  following option is  correct

$1. $$R$  has  exactly  two prime  ideal

$2.$$R$  is UFD

$3.$$(x)$ is  a maximal ideal of $R$

My attempt  :  $x^2+1 =(x-i)(x+i)$ so option $1$ is  true  that is R  has  exactly two prime ideal

$\frac{\mathbb{C}[x]}{(x^2+1)}$is isomorphics to $\mathbb{C}^2$  so we know that  $\mathbb{C^2} $is euclidean domain so  it will be UFD

option 3 is  obviously false

Is its  correct ??

Comment: It is $\mathbb{C} \times \mathbb{C}$, which is not even an integral domain. But it has exactly two prime  ideals.

Comment: Hi: i've edited your title to be more useful. Please consider carefully your future titles and make sure they are informative, rather than excuses for titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Your work in this is OK, but you haven't really justified why there are two prime ideals. Merely factoring into two rings does not guarantee that. It would be better to clarify how you arrive at that from your isomorphism with $\mathbb C\times \mathbb C$.

2) No, it is not even a domain.

3) If it is obvious then it should cost you little to give a simple reason. What is your reason? For an exercise in class, few people are going to have patience with someone who answers "obvious."